# command to find files by searching only part of their names and have 4 characters?

Tags: command-line

What command and how could I use it to :
 Display all files with the extension b , containing " v " in their names , containing 4 characters with an extension ?

```
Sand.b
Volume.h
Vacation.b
```

Comment: does extension is strictly `.b`, or could it be something like `.be`

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? what did you try?

Comment: +1 @steeldriver, that smells as good as an homework - Lets start with `find ./ -regextype sed -regex "learn2learn"` the cherry on the cake starts with the regex pattern.

Comment: @damadam                                                                   I tried this
find . -iname '* v * .b'
 I only worked the first part of the question,
But the part on the number of letters I do not find a solution

Comment: Add what you tried in the body of the question, click [edit] and then format the code with the tool {}

Comment: @steeldriver                                                                                                             
     I tried this
find.-iname '* v * .b'
 I only worked the first part of the question,
But the part on the number of letters I do not find a solution .

Comment: Could you explain better the conditions? When is "and" and when is "or"? The commas are confusing.

Comment: @guillermochamorro "and"